# Setting isHidden to false on x amount of elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to unhide n number of elements depending on the users input into a text field.

So the user enters a number between 1 - 5 in the text field then clicks submit which calls `createSplit`. As you can see, it unhides a view and then I want it to loop x (x being the number the user inputs) amount of times to unhide `day(i)View` textfield

```
    @IBAction func createSplit(_ sender: Any)
{
    noOfExerciseView.isHidden = false
    let noOfDays: Int = Int(numberOfDays.text!)!
    for i in 1...noOfDays
    {
        day\(i)View.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

I have a working solution but it's not the most efficient so I hope someone can help doing this an efficient way.

```
    @IBAction func createSplit(_ sender: Any)
{
    noOfExerciseView.isHidden = false
    let noOfDays: Int = Int(numberOfDays.text!)!
    for i in 1...noOfDays
    {
        if (i==1)
        {
            day1View.isHidden = false
        } else if (i==2)
        {
            day2View.isHidden = false
        } else if (i==3)
        {
            day3View.isHidden = false
        } else if (i==4)
        {
            day4View.isHidden = false
        } else if (i==5)
        {
            day5View.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a IBOutletCollection and iterating thought the view in the collection?

Comment: @ReinierMelian new to this so I was unaware about IBOutletCollection, how would this be implemented?

Comment: are those views created programatically? or in Storyboard/Xib?

Comment: @ReinierMelian created in Storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation cannot be used to set the name of a variable:

```
day\(i)View.isHidden // does not work
```

Your best bet is to use an outlet collection to define all your day views.

Instead of this:

```
@IBOutlet var day1View: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var day2View: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var day3View: UITextField!
//...
```

Do this:

```
@IBOutlet var dayViews: [UITextField]!
```

Then you can write your loop like this:

```
for i in 0...noOfDays-1
{
    dayViews[i].isHidden = false
}
```

Note that to do this, you'll need to delete the existing outlets and reconnect them.

If you're using a storyboard, then when you Control-drag from your first text field to your class file, select **Outlet Collection** for the Connection type and name it `dayViews`. To add the remaining text fields to the collection, just Control-drag from each one to the `dayViews` var in your class file.

Comment: I take it this would be the same, it's the UIStackView's I want to make visible.