# Swift variable inside variable for iteration

Tags: swift

I have very redundant code that I need to simplify as I am expanding and I am not sure how to do this. I have a lot of buttons that get updated and images changed quite often. Depending on what button is lit up and what is going on in the program, I change the state of a lot of buttons at once. I would like to create a function that can iterate multiple parts of the function. . .for example, below is a chunk of code that is repeated 1 time per button that I have, which at this point is going to be 48. . .

```
if sharedData.Channel1Mute != nil {
            if sharedData.Channel1Mute == "True" {
                self.Channel1Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "w1"), for:UIControlState())
            }
            else {
                self.Channel1Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "g1"), for:UIControlState())
            }
if sharedData.Channel2Mute != nil {
            if sharedData.Channel2Mute == "True" {
                self.Channel2Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "w2"), for:UIControlState())
            }
            else {
                self.Channel2Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "g2"), for:UIControlState())
            }
...
...
ect
...
```

This isn't correct coding but I would like this to function something like this which would be MUCH shorter and scalable . . .

```
for NUMBER in 1...48 {
    if sharedData.Channel[NUMBER]Mute != nil {
            if sharedData.Channel[NUMBER]Mute == "True" {
                self.Channel[NUMBER]Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "w[NUMBER]"), for:UIControlState())
            }
            else {
                self.Channel[NUMBER]Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "g[NUMBER]"), for:UIControlState())
            }
}
```

This is frustrating because my current code does the exact same thing like 48 times but I have to rewrite the whole code again with each number in the if statement in each copy.

Comment: What you want are outlet collections. They are easy to set up. Here's a start, but there are many other sources online that explain how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134422/setting-ishidden-to-false-on-x-amount-of-elements/49134856#49134856

Comment: See also view tags. You assign `tag` for each button with a number in Interface Builder (or in code) and use `viewWithTag` to extract it from the superview.

Comment: (One problem with outlet collections is that they're not reliably ordered, so you usually wind up having to either tag them anyway, or sort them by their location.)

Comment: @RobNapier Interesting, I haven't run into that, but good to know.

Comment: Even if I could use tags or outlet collections, that still wouldn't fix my problem of redundant code wouldn't it? I still need to connect the number of the button with the number of the image file. For example I need to connect white button 10 with w10.png . . .etc.  . .

Comment: That's `"w\(tag).png"`, which I thought is what you were looking for?